# Why doesn't my "Trusted Places" work anymore in my Samsung Galaxy s7?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, smart-lock

Since I just got an update for my Samsung Galaxy s7, my trusted places quit working. In fact, I cannot even find the setting in my settings section.

Comment: Go to settings/accessibility see if the app needs permission

Comment: Read the update FAQ. Maybe they have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned today from Samsung via the Smart Tutor app that Smart Lock trusted places can have trouble inside buildings if the location service is set to high accuracy using GPS. If the GPS signal is not found it causes a delay of 10 seconds which is too much for unlock to work.

To get it working I should set the location method to battery saving via:

> Android Quick Settings menu (pull down one finger from top)
>
> -> `location symbol` (slide one finger to the left)
>
> -> long press the `location symbol` for a few seconds to open the `Location` menu
>
> -> `Location method` -> `Battery saving`

However, Smart Lock still doesn't unlock sometimes. Adding more trusted places which differ only at the last digit seems to have improved the situation a bit. However, it is also still not working well for me.